# PassportJS authentication and mongodb database collection best practices?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, passport.js

I am working in a project and actually the first time using nodejs, express and mongodb. For the authentication i am using passport.js which look pretty flexible and easy to integrate it.

I really like the idea of Serializing and Deserializing but my concern is about the user object which is always ON and can be used on every request.

My project involve subscriptions, user profile and maybe a small ticked system.
So my user schema it contains user credentials, user info like address, phone, email and also information about the subscription. Some of this information is embedded documents with in same schema. It seems weird that all this info is always ready even i do not needed, even the bcrypt password is always on the request call.

My question is, do you think is best practice to separate the user credentials from the user object and play with relationships soi can call the user info when i need it with normal controller model way?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

if you are referring to sessions you should really only be sending a small piece of data with the request such as a user id. The entire user document should not be going across with every request.

Comment: Yes, that's what i was thinking. It makes sense. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's common practice to separate user credentials from the rest of the user data, because the credentials need to be stored in a very secure manner - so much so that it dictates different infrastructure.

I work at [Stormpath](https://stormpath.com) and we provide this as a service.  We store the password for you, with very high levels of encryption.  We have a great integration for Express, you check it out here:

https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-express